# Get last digits using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
10 101/12/201209/12/2012 8 75.00 600.00 2 1RPT/136185RAMADA HOTEL & SUITES
```

I want to get from this value from the string:

```
136185
```

I tried to use `/([^\/]*)$/`, but it returned:

```
136185RAMADA HOTEL
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is that number always six digits? What happens if it's shorter and the hotel name is "7 Seas"?

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "10 101/12/201209/12/2012 8 75.00 600.00 2 1RPT/136185RAMADA HOTEL & SUITES"

str[/\d+(?=\D*\z)/]
# => "136185"
```

Comment: You should download [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) great program for testing regex.  This answer works :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the shortest solution but `(\d+)\D*\Z` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of using `scan` is to use `split`:

```
    s = '10 101/12/201209/12/2012 8 75.00 600.00 2 1RPT/136185RAMADA HOTEL & SUITES'
    s.split(/\D+/).last # Everything that isn't a number is a separator, take the last one
    => "136185"
```

If the rule is first number after the last '/', then this works even if the business has digits in its name:

```
    s = '10 101/12/201209/12/2012 8 75.00 600.00 2 1RPT/136185MOTEL 6'
    s.split(?/).last.to_i # => 136185
```

Note that "7 Seas Hotel" is going to still cause problems

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string[/.*\b(\d+)/,1]
```

this matches as many characters as possible before matching a group of digits, starting with a word boundary to make sure the greedy `.*` doesn't eat up the begin of the digit group.

Or use

```
string.scan(/\d+/).last
```

which is more readable, but not a pure regex.

Comment: The `[...,1]` part select the first match group. I guess the website shows you the complete match rather than just the group. Try again using `irb` with the complete expression that I’ve provided.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is ALWAYS six digits, use:

```
'10 101/12/201209/12/2012 8 75.00 600.00 2 1RPT/136185RAMADA HOTEL & SUITES'.split[6].split('/').last[0, 6]
=> "136185"
```

The potential problem with any regex solution is the number + hotel name could cause solutions using `\d+` to return bad values if the hotel's name is something like `7 Seas`.